# VLcd pin to ground?

Tags: lcd, voltage-level

I just bought an ERC12864-655 LCD screen.

On the [datasheet](http://www.buydisplay.com/download/interfacing/ERC12864-655_Interfacing.pdf) it says that I need to connect the vlcd pin to GND.

However in [this](http://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ERC12864-655_Series_Datasheet.pdf) (page 8) datasheet it says that vlcd is the main power supply. As far as I know ground is no power supply. That doesn't make sense to me.

So what should I do with this pin?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the LCD is powered/switched by the chip, not directly powered externally. The 10K to ground would be a pulldown to keep pin 20 from floating when the LCD is not being powered, and the .33 uF cap would be for power filtering.

The datasheet pointed to by your second link is a quality-control document; not quite what most of us call a datasheet, but Note B on page 1 suggests more documentation is available on the manufacturer's website. Their interfacing description and demo code should help.